# Centered partial-width bottom-only borders on divs

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to achieve partial width borders on my list elements, the scss I'm using looks like this:

```
.parent{
  &__feature-name {
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: #fafafa;
  }
  &__feature-name:before {
    content: "";
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent__feature-name p-2"> example</div>
    <div class="parent__feature-name p-2"> example</div>
    <div class="parent__feature-name p-2"> example</div>
    <div class="parent__feature-name p-2"> example</div>
</div>
```

Now the result I'm getting looks like this:

[image]

- Issue 1: Border is top instead of bottom
- Issue 2: The text is not vertically aligned: `d-flex` and `align-items-center` just align the line in the center, it doesn't move the text

I've wrote a codepen with my code: https://codepen.io/thehussein/pen/dyXyOxW
(Note that in the codepen the lines are extending outside the parent - I'm just concerned here with moving them to the bottom and having the text vertically aligned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To position the border at the bottom, you need to make 2 changes to your CSS rules:

1. Specify that the line should be at the `bottom:0` of the absolute-positioned element:

```
.parent__feature-name:before { bottom:0; }
```

2. Make the parent element `position: relative` so that the absolute position will be relative to this, i.e.:

```
.parent__feature-name { position: relative; }
```

**Working Demo** (using CSS):

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
}
.parent__feature-name {
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  position: relative;
}
.parent__feature-name:before {
  content: "";
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent__feature-name p-2"> example</div>
    <div class="parent__feature-name p-2"> example</div>
    <div class="parent__feature-name p-2"> example</div>
    <div class="parent__feature-name p-2"> example</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very clean and well-explained, thanks I appreciate the help!